# 戻り値についてとvoidについて

Tags: java

現在javaの学習中です。
復習として簡単なコードを打ち込んでそれを学んで自分が覚えている範囲から書き換えているのですがnumの値を表すコードを書いてみました。
P１：

```
class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num = 100;
        System.out.println("This num is " + num);
    }
}
```

といった構文をまず　P２：

```
class XXX {
    void display() {
        int num;
        num = 100;
        System.out.println("This num is " + num);
    }
}
class sample1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        XXX p1 = new XXX();
        p1.display();
    }
}
```

と書いてみてその次に
P3：

```
class XXX {
    void display() {
        int num;
        num = 100;
        System.out.println("This num is " + num);
    }
}
class sample1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        XXX p1 = new XXX();
        p1.display();
        sample3(20);
    }
    public static void sample3(int num1) {
        System.out.println("This num1 is " + num1);
    }
}
```

と書き加えてみました。
P3についてはネットに記述していたやつを真似て作成してみたのですが、
ここでvoid sample3(int num1)についてよくわからなく
void というのは引数が空のときにつかうものではないのでしょうか。
引数　int num1というのが書かれているのにどうしてvoidをつけないといけないのでしょうか。
また

```
class XXX {
    void display(int num) {
        num = 100;
        System.out.println("This num is " + num);
    }
}
class sample1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        XXX p1 = new XXX();
        p1.display();
    }
}
```

といった記述にしてみたんですが、自分はp1.displayは空のvoid dsplay(int num)に戻って
num = 100をいれて　This num is 100とだされると考えていたのですがエラーがでてしまいました。

```
class XXX {
    void display(int num) {
        System.out.println("This num is " + num);
    }
}
class sample1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        XXX p1 = new XXX();
        p1.display(100);
    }
}
```

といった記述にすれば問題なくだされるのですが戻り値といったものや引数の約束事やその仕様、voidなどがいまいちわかりません。よろしくお願いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void sample3(int num1){`

この場合の`void` は、メソッドの戻り値がないことを示します。

```
int mul2(int num){
    return num*2;
}
```

のようにint をvoid の代わりに書いた場合は、
メソッドはint の値を返すことを示します。
この場合`return` 文を使って値を返す必要があります。

なので、(ここでのvoidは)返す値についてのものなので引数(のあるなし)とは関係ありません。

`(int num1)` の部分については、このメソッドはint の値を引数として必要なことを示します。
引数なしにこのメソッドを呼び出すことはできません。

引数なしに呼びだそうとする場合には、引数無しのメソッドを書く必要があります。

---

`void display()` の場合 `p.display()`のように呼び出す、`p.display(数値)`の様には呼び出せない。
`void display(int num)` の場合 `p.display(数値)`のように呼び出す、`p.display()`の様に(int の引数が必要で引数なしに)は呼び出せない。
それぞれのメソッドの要件を満たしていない場合そのメソッドは呼び出されません。

---

メソッドの定義部分（`void sample3(int num1){`のような部分）は、

Ａ｛void｝ Ｂ｛sample3｝(Ｃ｛int num1｝)
Ａ，Ｂ，Ｃの部分は
Ａ｛値を返すかどうか返すとしたらその型｝ Ｂ｛メソッド名｝(Ｃ｛引数があるかないかあるとしたらその引数の並び｝)
というようになっていて、
これはつまりは対外的なインターフェースを表していて、
（実際の中身については実際に何が行われるかは使う側は知る必要はない、何を入れれば何がでてくるかだけ分かっていればよいという意味でこの部分を知ってればよい）
このメソッドの機能（何を受け取って何を返すか(または受け取らず返さない)）を外観するものです。
だから単に書き方の違いというか、その機能によって(返す値や引数が)決まるものです。

Comment: いつもすぐに回答していただきありがとうございます。
return文で値を返すとありますがそれは引数とreturnの違いというのは書き方の違いだけととってもいいのでしょうか。
別のコードを自分でうってみたのですが
　　　`class time {
 　　public static void main(String args[]){
  　double r = 3000;
  　double s = 75;
  　double t ;
  　t = r / s ;
  　NY_LAtime(t);
　 　}
 　public static double NY_LAtime(double t){
  System.out.println("NYからLAまでにかかる時間は　" + t);
  return t;
 }}`
と　
　　　　`class time {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  double r = 3000;
  double s = 75;
  double t ;
  t = r / s ;
  NY_LAtime(t);
 }
 public static void NY_LAtime(double t){
  System.out.println("NYからLAまでにかかる時間は　" + t);
 }}`

Comment: の結果は同じでした。retunは値を返すとのことですがreturnとvoidの役割や使いわけがいまいちわかりません。
メソッドについての要件さえみたしてればどう記述しても問題ないということですか？
メッソドについて理解が薄いのでメソッドについて勉強しときます。

Comment: @user10197  `int a2 = `mul2`(3);` のような場合`mul2`は、６を返してそれがa2に代入されます。値を返すメソッドの場合その返値を受け取ることが想定されます。受け取らない場合は返値は単に捨てられます。逆に値を返さないメソッドで`int a2 = noreturn(3);` のようなことはできません。問題があるかどうかはプログラムとしての整合性の問題になります。

Comment: @user10197  例えば`System.out.println(NY_LAtime(3000.0/75.0))`のような場合をそれぞれ試してみて下さい。

Comment: System.out.println(NY_LAtime(3000.0/75.0))を自分なりに試したのですが
　``class time {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  double d;
  d = 3000.0/75.0;
  NY_LAtime(d);
 }
 public static double NY_LAtime(double d){
  // P1:System.out.println(NY_LAtime(3000.0/75.0));
  System.out.println(NY_LAtime(d));
  return NY_LAtime(d);
 }}``
の場合コードで間違いはないがエラーがでて
コメントの欄のやつもエラーがでてしまいます。
またreturn NY_LAtime(3000/75.0)にしてもエラーがでます。
作成中にvoidでやろうとしたところそれはできないといわれました。
Ａ｛void｝ Ｂ｛sample3｝(Ｃ｛int num1｝)というのはその役割があるというより
こうやったら客観的に見てなにが起こってるかわかりやすいからこう書きましょう。というようなものですか？

Comment: つまり、`System.out.println(NY_LAtime(3000.0/75.0))` で `NY_LAtime` が値を返さない場合はエラーになり、値を返す場合は返した値が表示されます。「どう書いても違いは無い」というのは返値を使うようなコードでなかったからというわけです。

Comment: メソッドには要求される仕様というか機能があってそれを表現していることになります。（わかりやすいからとかわかりにくいからというのはちょっとはずしていると思います。）例えば、速度を求める機能のメソッドの場合、距離と掛かった時間を引数に取って速度を返すというような仕様が考えられます。それをプログラムとして表現すると `double velocity
(double distance_km, double hour)` のように（一例）表現するということになります。